# Validity of an app-scoped user ID on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

just a simple question that bothers me.

Is the app-scoped ID of a user valid forever or just for a certain time? Also, resulting from that, is the link to the user's timeline retrieved from the API valid forever?

I need to know that because I need the user's ID and timeline link. And I want to know whether this is something I have to do just once or regularily.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Once a user logged in to your app for the first time, the id your app sees for them will stay the same. (If you are getting ids for users that did _not_ connect to your app already from somewhere, then those _will_ change once they login.) And yes, the profile links will stay valid.

Comment: You might find this useful: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids